# Why git fetch doesn't download anything?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fetch

I'm trying to download my project which is uploaded on bitbucket on my local directory. As far as I know about `git fetch`, it should download the project *(but not `merge` it)*.

Well I have a connection to my repository as well, an here is what I've done:

[image]

And this is the result of `git fetch`: *(as you see it in the image above)*

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 114, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
remote: Total 114 (delta 6), reused 114 (delta 6)
Receiving objects: 100% (114/114), 10.32 MiB | 2.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/lamtakam/lamtakam
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

But nothing downloaded ..! Why? As you see, my local directory is empty *(except `.git` folder)*. What's wrong?

Comment: Try `git checkout master` now.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh .. :-) great ..! I can see all folders/files on my local directory now ..! What was the problem?

Comment: The "problem" is that `git fetch` merely *obtains commits* from some other Git. This is what you want, since you can now combine *their* commits with *your* commits, or use theirs as yours, or look at theirs and look at yours, etc.

Comment: The commits _were_ downloaded. You just didn't specify which one you want to see.

Comment: @torek Ah thank you ..!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah I see, btw, git seems bullshit ..! It would be much better if it show me the master **by default**.

Comment: @stack: it does that when you do `git clone`. It's not git's fault that you used a wrong command.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev hmm, really?! Ok I take that back .. Can you please tell me what exactly happens when I execute `git fetch`? The files will be downloaded in where place?

Comment: @stack: also it would do you good to actually learn git concepts before you call it names (working copy, index, fetch, merge, HEAD, etc.)

Comment: @stack: when you do `git fetch`, remote commits are downloaded into `.git` hidden folder. Now they're ready to be inspected, merged, checked out or whatever.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah I see, thank you .. And `git checkout master` means *"show the files which are in the master branch"* ?

Comment: @stack: yes, `git checkout master` gets you on your `master` branch. There is a trap here though: the *first time* you do it, Git creaes *your* `master` matching the `origin/master` you just cloned-or-fetched. After that, though, your `master` is now yours—separate—and you need to `git merge` or `git rebase` your own master with incoming commits. There is a convenience command, `git pull`, that runs both `git fetch` and the second command, but except for some cases, it turns out to be more *in*convenient and I generally recommend avoiding it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Got it *(almost)*, my current confusion is: *(as you see in the image I've provided in my question)*, when I wrote `git status`, git told me `on branch master` ..! Well, what did I need to use `checkout` then?!

Comment: @torek Ah I see, good to know, thank you

Comment: (typo above, should read "creates") In a new empty repository, you are in a special peculiar state: you're on what Git calls an *unborn branch*, or sometimes *orphan branch*. That is, `master` exists, but hasn't been created! It's a special case Git uses because Git can't have a branch that has no commits, yet a brand-new repository has no commits. You'll only encounter it once unless you use `git checkout --orphan` to create a new unborn branch.

Comment: "Receiving updates..."  This _is_ git downloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

git fetch simply update(s) your `.git` folder with the packed data.
It does not update your working directory only the internal .git folder.

Once all the data downloaded you can checkout any branch you want to work on.

#### `git fetch`

> The `git fetch` command imports commits from a remote repository into **your local repo** (no to be confused with the local working directory).
>
> The resulting commits are stored as **remote branches** instead of the
>    normal local branches that we’ve been working with. This gives you a
>    chance to review changes before integrating them into your copy of the
>    project.

---

To see the list of available branches use the `-a` flag

```
# display all available branches
git branch -a
```

[image]

In order to work on specific branch simply check out the desired branch

[image]